# Desperation 死に物狂い

Tags: meaning

I came across a sentence that said:

> [死]{し}に[物狂]{ものぐる}いになれる[環境]{かんきょう}が[相応]{ふさわ}しい

but I don't understand what he means by saying "死に物狂い", an environment where he can struggle to the death or to make him desperate?

Comment: From https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/99511/meaning/m0u/ 死ぬことも恐れないでがんばること

Comment: I'm afraid i still don't understand

Comment: What is the context? What is happening before the sentence 「死に物狂いになれる環境が相応しい」is mentioned? Judging by the sentence alone, we can only guess for an accurate meaning.
For example, I can imagine a general and his men. The sentence can mean a situation (環境 can mean "situation" depending on context) where the general is deliberately creating a desperate situation to force his men to become stronger fighters if they wish to survive.

Answer (score 2):

I am a native speaker of Japanese but not of English. So my English may not be natural but I hope to be helpful.

Your understanding is right.

死に物狂いになれる環境=an enviorment where he can struggle to the death or to make him desperate

As a side note,
死に物狂い's definition is 死ぬことも恐れないでがんばること。(=to work hard even not being afraid of death even if you can die)（quoted from goo Japanese-to-Japanese  dictionary)

e.g. 彼は死に物狂いになって戦った。(= He fought, not being afraid of death)

Comment: `彼は死に物狂いになって戦った He fought, not being afraid of death` <--  "fought like hell" とか "fought desperately" とかのほうが近いような気が...